# grpc-java, available field names for the method:ManagedChannelBuilder.defaultServiceConfig()

Tags: channel, grpc-java

```
 Class : ManagedChannelBuilder
 Method : defaultServiceConfig(Map<String,?> serviceConfig)
 Available field names : MethodConfig, retryPolicy etc...
```

https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#defaultServiceConfig-java.util.Map-

I am trying to create a parameter for the method but cannot find the available field names. I need a list of the field names for the serviceConfig. 
Where can I find the list or do I need to look into the source code to find them out?

Comment: gRPC doesn't provide comprehensive list of this service config. are you looking for a specific functionality? some of the service config can be found in https://github.com/grpc/proposal  e.g) A6 has retry hedging example.

Comment: The comprehensive list of the config is what I am looking for. I understood it is not provided but am wondering why it is not. Isn't this something we need?

Comment: actually i found a better one. https://github.com/grpc/grpc-proto/blob/master/grpc/service_config/service_config.proto#L377

Comment: As you can see there aren't many, it is mostly used by LoadBalancer implementations. i am not sure how useful it is tbh are you looking for a specific feature?

Comment: Thank you for the information.this is what I needed.

Comment: Could you post the link as an answer if you have a chance?

Comment: sure, glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service config definition is defined in [this proto](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-proto/blob/master/grpc/service_config/service_config.proto#L377).

Service config object (`Map<String, Object>`) is a JSON like representation of the ServiceConfig protobuf. Note that field names in the map should be in lower camel case.

Comment: It's really confusing that it's not using the actual Proto. Do you know where one would get this Proto from?